# Management Studio Diffrent files after backup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-backups

I have database in SQL Server Managment Studio. I make a backup of my database using this script:

```
    use mydatabase

    BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase
    TO DISK = 'D:\mydatabase\backup.BAK'
    GO

    BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase
    TO DISK =  'E:\mydatabase\work.BAK'
    GO
```

My problem is that the files backup.BAK and work.BAK have the same size. I check every byte and this files are not the same. Did anyone know why?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but this is not surprising. The time will have changed between the two backups and there is likely to have been some change in the data if the database is live. The size may not change though as the number of pages may have remained the same even though some of the padding may have been replaced with data.

Comment: `NOT THE SAME` is a very vague term, Do you mean they are not same in size ? If the difference is in size and data hasn't changed, since they are on different drives maybe one of them is compressed and other isn't.

Comment: Or "size on disk" reflects two drives with different block sizes or completely different underlying storage architectures (is one a thumb drive? is one a SAN? is one FAT32 vs. NTFS? etc). Agreed with @M.Ali, what does "not the same" mean? How exactly are you checking the size?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your database, it may take a while to generate the backup. Depending on the activity, a lot can change in the database during this time. To create exact copies of your backup file, you should just copy the first backup file. You can do this in SQL, for example:

```
DECLARE @SourceFile AS VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @DestinationFile AS VARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(500);  

BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase
TO DISK = 'D:\mydatabase\backup.BAK'
GO

SET @SourceFile = 'D:\mydatabase\backup.BAK'
SET @DestinationFile = 'E:\mydatabase\work.BAK'

SET @Cmd = 'COPY ' + @SourceFile + ' ' + @DestinationFile; 
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Cmd;
```

Comment: But my database is empty. Any application use my database. That`s why I could not understand why my files (backup.BAK, work.BAK) are different.